# Assign pointer-to-pointer in for loop C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to store a 2-d array in a pointer-to-pointer iteratively. I'm filling it with random Gaussian values, but that's not the important part. I try to fill the array pointed to by `A` but get a "bad access code" error. How would I correctly fill the array/pointer? Thanks.

int main() {

```
int N = 100;
double **A[N][N];
for(int i = 0; i< N; i++){
    for(int j =0; j < N; j++){
        random_device rd;
        default_random_engine generator;
        generator.seed( rd() );
        normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);
        **A[i][j] = distribution(generator); // error here, bad access code 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that your second line declares a two-dimensional array of  **pointers** to **double pointers**. you can only change the values at `A[i][j]`. If you want to assign value to `**A[i][j]`, you must first allocate memory for it using `new`.

Comment: Warning: You do not want to reseed the random number generator every time you use it. Very expensive and may result in always getting the same number, depending on the implementation of `std::random_device`. Seed the generator only once near the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, change `double **A[N][N];` to `double **A;`. You want a double pointer, not a matrix of double pointers. Then, you have to allocate memory like this: `A=new double*[N];` and then `for(i=0;i<N;i++) A[i]=new double[n];` Then everything will work fine.  You will access an element of the matrix in the normal way, `A[i][j]` , not `**A[i][j]`!
This sample code will familiarize you with the concept:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int n=100;

    double **a;
    a=new double*[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) a[i]=new double[n];

    a[1][2]=3;

    std::cout<<a[1][2];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) delete a[i];
    delete[] a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. Now the problem is I'm trying to use the svdcomp.C program to which you have to pass a double pointer. When I pass **A it gives me the error 'no matching function for call.' Any thoughts or suggestions here?

Comment: @PatEugene You might want to ask that in a seperate question

Comment: Unless `N` is too large to put `A` on the stack, consider using `double A[N][N];` instead.  If you do use the heap, you could use `double **A = (double**) new byte[sizeof(double) * (N*N)]; ... delete[] (byte*) A;` to perform only 1 big allocation instead of having to perform N+1 smaller allocations.  Or use `std::vector<std::vector<double>> A;` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare a static array using a non-const integer for its dimensions.

You are declaring an array of pointers, but the pointers do not point at any valid memory, which is why you are getting memory errors.

Try this instead:

```
const int N = 100;

double A[N][N];

random_device rd;
default_random_engine generator;
generator.seed( rd() );
normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);

for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        A[i][j] = distribution(generator);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, allocate the array on the heap instead of the stack (then you can use a non-const int for dimensions):

```
int N = 100;

double **A = new double*[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    A[i] = new double[N];
}

random_device rd;
default_random_engine generator;
generator.seed( rd() );
normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);

for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        A[i][j] = distribution(generator);
    }
}

...

for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    delete[] A[i];
}
delete[] A;
```

Or this:

```
int N = 100;

double *A = new double[N*N];

random_device rd;
default_random_engine generator;
generator.seed( rd() );
normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);

for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        A[(i*N)+j] = distribution(generator);
    }
}

...

delete[] A;
```

With that said, it is better to use `std::vector` instead of `new[]` manually:

```
int N = 100;

std::vector<std::vector<double> > A(N);
for(int i = 0; i< N; i++) {
    A[i].resize(N);
}

random_device rd;
default_random_engine generator;
generator.seed( rd() );
normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);

for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        A[i][j] = distribution(generator);
    }
}
```

Or:

```
int N = 100;

std::vector<double> A(N*N);

random_device rd;
default_random_engine generator;
generator.seed( rd() );
normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);

for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        A[(i*N)+j] = distribution(generator);
    }
}
```

Comment: @M.M: I changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
**A[i][j] = distribution(generator);
```

`A[i][j]` stores the value of type `double**`. So you need to first store your random value in a valid address, and then store it in `A`.

```
/*Assign a new double* pointer to A[i][j]*/
A[i][j] = new double*;

/*Assign a new double pointer which is addressed by A[i][j]*/
*A[i][j] = new double;

/*Assign value to **A[i][j] */
**A[i][j] = distribution(generator);
```

Comment: `A[i][j] = distribution(generator)` would assign a pointer to a double pointer (`double**`) a value of  `double`

Comment: @Polikdir I do not know what value the function `distribution()` returns, and thought it would be of type `double**`. It would be great if you could tell.

Comment: You should've checked the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution/operator()) before assuming such things. It's also pretty intuitive.